# monogodb get sum of one field of in sub document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm pretty new with monogodb and I'm trying to use the aggregation framework to get the sum of revenue for each agent.

My data looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56ce2ce5b69c4a909eb50f22"),
    "property_id" : 5594,
    "reservation_id" : "3110414.1",
    "arrival" : "2016-02-24",
    "los" : 1,
    "updated" : ISODate("2016-02-24T22:21:27.000Z"),
    "offer_list" : {
        "68801" : {
            "pitched" : "yes",
            "accepted" : "yes",
            "prime_price" : "3",
            "agent_price" : "",
            "price_per" : "night"
        },
        "63839" : {
            "pitched" : "yes",
            "accepted" : "yes",
            "prime_price" : "8",
            "agent_price" : "",
            "price_per" : "night"
        }
    },
    "status" : "accepted",
    "comments" : [],
    "created" : ISODate("2016-02-24T22:21:18.000Z"),
    "agent_id" : 50941
}
```

For each agent_id, I would like to get the sum of all "agent_price" (or "prime_price" if "agent_price" is None) multiplied by field "los" when "accepted"=="yes".

For the example above the expected output would be:

```
{'sum':11, 'agent_id": 50941}
```

The sum is the two "accepted" "prime_price" (8+3) times los (1) = 11.

I tried to use $unwind but it only works for a list, not object. Can anyone help on that?

Comment: You do realize that both `prime_price` and `agent_price` are string right?

Comment: Yes. Will need to parse it to int for this example.

Comment: @zangw with the exception of course that all the "price" items would need to be numeric and the example "array" structure would have to be valid. Your edit on the example was probably done a little too hastily.

Comment: @BlakesSeven, my bad, thank you for your correction...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt it is possible with aggregation, yet should be straightforward with [mapreduce](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/):

```
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function(){
        for(key in this.offer_list) {
            if (this.offer_list[key].accepted == 'yes') {
                if (this.offer_list[key].agent_price == '') {
                    emit(this.agent_id, this.los * this.offer_list[key].prime_price);
                } else {
                    emit(this.agent_id, this.los * this.offer_list[key].agent_price);
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    function(agent, values) {
        return Array.sum(values);
    }
)
```

For real-life code, I would also add a [query option](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/) for data sanitation.